# export drupal2drupal migrate settings

Tags: 7, migrations

I am using the drupal2drupal UI for a D7 to D7 migration. Is there anyway I can export the setting for the migration including the connection string and the field mappings so that we can repeat the exact migration on another server without having to repeat the UI setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature request for the Migrate module: [Export migration configuration as code](https://www.drupal.org/node/1983404). Beware that this is highly experimental! Here is the summary of the issue:

1. Apply [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/migrate-export_config_as_code-1983404-10_1.patch) to the Migrate module and be sure to clear cache. This patch makes your configuration exportable as a [Feature](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).
2. You can now create a new Feature on the source site and select your configuration inside the Migrate fieldgroup. Check all options that apply and download/export your Feature.
3. Copy the Feature to your target site, enable it and then revert it to copy all your settings.

Comment: I reverted it but nothing shows up, and when I run drush ms I get :No source_version provided in migrate_d2d migration arguments.

Comment: Actually the feature works partially, I had to put in the connection string again but other wise the other things were stored.  thanks